# Show $n\log(n^2 + constant)$ is $\in \Theta(n\log n)$

Tags: asymptotics

As mentioned in the title, I have to show that $n\log(n^2 + 21) + 11\log(n) \in \Theta(n\log n)$. I am having quite a headache over trying to split the summation in $n\log()$ and I don't really know what to do. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: One possible approach: if you can show $n^3\ge n^2+21$ for large enough $n$, then $2n\log n = n\log(n^2)\le n\log(n^2+21)\le n\log(n^3) = 3n\log n$.

Comment: That was a big help, I was pulling off my hair over trying to solve it using $log(a + b) = log(a) + log(1 + b/a)$. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
n\log(n^2+21) & =n\log(\mathcal O(n^2)) \\
& =n\log(\mathcal O(n)^2) \\
& =2n\log(\mathcal O(n))
\end{align}$$

$$n\log(n^2+21)+11\log(n)=2n\log(\mathcal O(n))+11\log(\mathcal O(n))=(2n+11)\log(\mathcal O(n))$$

You could also use $n^2+21<n^3$ as Joey Zou suggests, and you will get the same result.

Comment: I would avoid using using notation like $\log( \mathcal{O}(n^2))$ for basic questions like this, as it can be misleading.  For example, $e^{n^2 +n} = e^{\mathcal{O}(n^2) }$ but $e^{n^2 +n}$ is not $\mathcal{O}(e^{n^2})$.

Comment: @JairTaylor Definitely true, but the taking out of the `^2` is indeed possible here.  $\ddot\smile$  Actually not terribly difficult to show.  Think I should've perfect squared the problem?

Comment: I agree the idea is kosher here, but I think you've basically absorbed the important part of the proof into the notation.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to solve the question I was stuck on.

Comment: @user3436204 $\ddot\smile$ sure thing!  Cheers!